# How to get the coefficient list of their product from the coefficient list of two polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

If I have the coefficient list of two polynomials

```
f1=x^3 a[1]+x^2 y a[2]+x^2 a[3]+x y^2 a[4]+x y a[5]+x a[6]+y^3 a[7]+y^2 a[8]+y a[9]+a[10];f2=x^2 b[1]+x y b[2]+x b[3]+y^2 b[4]+y b[5]+b[6]`, `A={{a[10],a[9],a[8],a[7]},{a[6],a[5],a[4],0},{a[3],a[2],0,0},{a[1],0,0,0}};B={{b[6],b[5],b[4]},{b[3],b[2],0},{b[1],0,0}}
```

How can I get the coefficient list

```
AB={{a[10] b[6],a[10] b[5]+a[9] b[6],a[10] b[4]+a[9] b[5]+a[8] b[6],a[9] b[4]+a[8] b[5]+a[7] b[6],a[8] b[4]+a[7] b[5],a[7] b[4]},{a[10] b[3]+a[6] b[6],a[10] b[2]+a[9] b[3]+a[6] b[5]+a[5] b[6],a[9] b[2]+a[8] b[3]+a[6] b[4]+a[5] b[5]+a[4] b[6],a[8] b[2]+a[7] b[3]+a[5] b[4]+a[4] b[5],a[7] b[2]+a[4] b[4],0},{a[10] b[1]+a[6] b[3]+a[3] b[6],a[9] b[1]+a[6] b[2]+a[5] b[3]+a[3] b[5]+a[2] b[6],a[8] b[1]+a[5] b[2]+a[4] b[3]+a[3] b[4]+a[2] b[5],a[7] b[1]+a[4] b[2]+a[2] b[4],0,0},{a[6] b[1]+a[3] b[3]+a[1] b[6],a[5] b[1]+a[3] b[2]+a[2] b[3]+a[1] b[5],a[4] b[1]+a[2] b[2]+a[1] b[4],0,0,0},{a[3] b[1]+a[1] b[3],a[2] b[1]+a[1] b[2],0,0,0,0},{a[1] b[1],0,0,0,0,0}}
```

of their product $f1*f2$ from `A` and `B`?

Or is there a built-in function `func` such that `func[A,B]==AB`?

Comment: `CoefficientList[f1 f2,{x,y}]` will produce the coefficients of the product.

Comment: @DanielHuber I mean to get the coefficient list through list operation instead through polynomials.

Comment: See [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html) > Applications > "Multiply polynomials by convolving coefficient lists".

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by convolving the lists of coefficients.  Defining

```
f1 = x^3 a[1] + x^2 y a[2] + x^2 a[3] + x y^2 a[4] + x y a[5] + 
  x a[6] + y^3 a[7] + y^2 a[8] + y a[9] + a[10];
f2 = x^2 b[1] + x y b[2] + x b[3] + y^2 b[4] + y b[5] + b[6];

A = CoefficientList[f1, {x, y}];

B = CoefficientList[f2, {x, y}];
```

The coefficient list for the product can be found either as

```
AB1 = CoefficientList[f1 f2, {x, y}];
```

or more efficiently (I hope) as

```
AB2 = ListConvolve[A, B, {1, -1}, 0];
```

The 3rd and 4th argument ensure that the arrays are appropriately padded with zeros.  (See [ListConvolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html))

Verifying the correspondence

```
AB1 == AB2
(* True *)
```

Comment: I put a link to  [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html) under the OP, but it probably belongs as part of this answer. (+1) -- definitely not easy to find in the docs, unless you already know about it. Apparently no duplicates either, which is amazing after all this time. (At least I didn't find one.)

Comment: Agreeing with @MichaelE2 (and upvoting). This really should be easier to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A = {{a[10], a[9], a[8], a[7]}, {a[6], a[5], a[4], 0}, {a[3], a[2], 0, 
   0}, {a[1], 0, 0, 0}}; 
B = {{b[6], b[5], b[4]}, {b[3], b[2], 0}, {b[1], 0, 
   0}};
```

[`FromDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html) and [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) can be used to reconstruct a multivariate polynomial

```
fromCoef[mat_, var_ : {x, y}] := Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, mat, var]

AB = CoefficientList[Times @@ fromCoef /@ {A, B}, {x, y}]

(* {{a[10] b[6], a[10] b[5] + a[9] b[6], a[10] b[4] + a[9] b[5] + a[8] b[6], 
  a[9] b[4] + a[8] b[5] + a[7] b[6], a[8] b[4] + a[7] b[5], 
  a[7] b[4]}, {a[10] b[3] + a[6] b[6], 
  a[10] b[2] + a[9] b[3] + a[6] b[5] + a[5] b[6], 
  a[9] b[2] + a[8] b[3] + a[6] b[4] + a[5] b[5] + a[4] b[6], 
  a[8] b[2] + a[7] b[3] + a[5] b[4] + a[4] b[5], a[7] b[2] + a[4] b[4], 
  0}, {a[10] b[1] + a[6] b[3] + a[3] b[6], 
  a[9] b[1] + a[6] b[2] + a[5] b[3] + a[3] b[5] + a[2] b[6], 
  a[8] b[1] + a[5] b[2] + a[4] b[3] + a[3] b[4] + a[2] b[5], 
  a[7] b[1] + a[4] b[2] + a[2] b[4], 0, 
  0}, {a[6] b[1] + a[3] b[3] + a[1] b[6], 
  a[5] b[1] + a[3] b[2] + a[2] b[3] + a[1] b[5], 
  a[4] b[1] + a[2] b[2] + a[1] b[4], 0, 0, 0}, {a[3] b[1] + a[1] b[3], 
  a[2] b[1] + a[1] b[2], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {a[1] b[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```